# Torn wallboard repair

Tags: drywall

When replacing door trim the wallboard PAPER came off! how do I repair this 6’ x 1’ strip along side door frame?
Do I joint compound plaster?

Comment: Did you intend to include a photo? You'll  need to host it elsewhere until you have a bit of reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the damage, it usually involves skimming with joint compound, sanding lightly, priming and painting. Trim away any loose material first.